# Which date does the order parameter on the List Orders endpoint for the Square API use to sort orders?

Tags: square-connect

An [Order](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/#datatype-order) has a `created_at` and `updated_at` date. Which one does the "List Orders" endpoint use to sort orders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Order objects are sorted by `created_at` date.

Comment: Thanks Troy. This does make what I am doing a little difficult, but I will ask that in a separate question. Thanks!